# Not Incrementing Rows

Tags: excel, vba

I have a Macro that makes a header and I wanted to create a variant of it that allows me to append my array called `headers()` to the next empty row in a sheet. I've tried playing around with the macro even replacing the `Range.insert` with `PasteSpecial` however the results are the same: Whenever I run the Macro in the VBA Editor it appends rows like I want, however when I run it via a Command button as a part of another sub it just overwrites the same row (row 2) even if I fill in row 2 with something.

```
Sub MEData()
    ' Find Next Empty Row & Append ME Data

    Dim headers() As Variant
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim lastRow As Long
    Dim lr As Long
    Set wb = ActiveWorkbook
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("ME Data")

    If DesignChangeECN = "" Then
        DesignChangeECN = "Not Design Change"
    End If

    headers() = Array(VBA.Environ("UserName"), Now(), MPP_ECN, 
    MPP_ECN_Description, DesignChangeECN, Dept, ShortChangeDescription, 
    ChangeType, "Additional Notes", _
    "Open", "Submitted")

    lastRow = Cells(ws.Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).row

    Rows(lastRow).PasteSpecial
    With ws
    For i = LBound(headers()) To UBound(headers())
        .Cells(lastRow, 1 + i).Value = headers(i)
        Next i
    End With

End Sub
```

I'm not super proficient in VBA so I'm not sure if I'm misusing or utilizing something incorrectly or if there is something super simple that I'm missing.

Comment: Have you tried qualifying your `Cells` reference when getting the last row? Or qualifying the `Rows` reference when inserting?

Comment: I'm not even sure why you need to insert, if you're writing into the next empty row.

Comment: @braX I figured my reference was correct because I declared a workbook and sheet. .

Comment: @BigBen insert might be the wrong tool to use here, I'm thinking that I should be doing some sort of append or write? I'm not super fluent in VBA so a lot of my code is a bit rough.

Comment: Declaring a workbook and worksheet doesn't do anything if you don't use it.

Comment: @braX I used worksheet down with the for loop. . However I did make an edit and change some of the lastRow code to be ws.Rows.Count as I must've missed that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer after quite a few hours of reading and research best methods of handling arrays and rows. I settled on using a range instead of insert as that would make more sense, especially when I figured out that I could have a range set to my array It became simpler.

I did still immediately suffer from not incrementing rows however I fix that by having using `ws.Activate` I figured out that since the sheet that ran the Macro via a command button was acting as the "Active Sheet" called `.Activate` fixed my issue.

```
Sub MEData()
    ' Find Next Empty Row & Append ME Data

    Dim headers() As Variant
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim lastRow As Long
    Set wb = ActiveWorkbook
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("ME Data")

    If DesignChangeECN = "" Then
        DesignChangeECN = "Not Design Change"
    End If

    headers() = Array(VBA.Environ("UserName"), Now(), MPP_ECN, MPP_ECN_Description, _
    DesignChangeECN, Dept, ShortChangeDescription, ChangeType, "Additional Notes", _
    "Open", "Submitted")
    ws.Activate
    lastRow = Cells(ws.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).row + 1
    ws.Range("A" & lastRow & ":K" & lastRow) = headers()

End Sub
```